# How to access the Recent call list in the iPhone Phone app?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Assume an iPhone is jailbroke, is there (private/public) API or database to access the recent phone call list? I'd like to delete an individual Recent call entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing iphone call log through code has been discussed many times.

The answers say that it is possible on a jail broken iphone. You need to access the data base:

> /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

But of course there aren't any public APIs for doing that.
I'm not sure how your jail broken iphone is going to react to your playing with this DB.
So i would suggest not deleting anything programmatically.